# Grouping and nesting data produces an error in R with tidyverse

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyverse

I'm trying to calculate some home range estimates for some animal tracking data. To do so the authors of the amt package [recommend grouping by ID and then nesting](https://movebankworkshopraleighnc.netlify.app/2019outputfiles/testvignettemovebank).

But when I do so I get the following error:

> Error: The `groups` attribute is not a data frame with its last column
> called `.rows`.

Here's an example that reproduces the error:

```
library(amt)
library(tidyverse)

    data(deer)
    mini_deer <- deer[1:100, ]
    nesttrk <- mini_deer %>% group_by(burst_) %>% 
      nest() 
    nesttrk
```

The overall aim is to get a home range size estimate per ID (or burst_ in this case)

```
mini_deer %>% group_by(burst_) %>%  nest(-burst_) %>%
  mutate(mcparea = map(data, ~ hr_mcp(., levels = c(0.95)) %>% hr_area)) %>%
  dplyr::select(burst_, mcparea) %>% unnest()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have not used `amt` package but from the error message using `nest` it seems that it requires data in some specific format as nesting with dataframe works without any problem. (`mini_deer %>% as.data.frame() %>% group_by(burst_) %>% nest()`) but we loose the class as we are converting to dataframe.

Split and combine approach works -

```
library(amt)
library(tidyverse)

mini_deer %>% 
  group_split(burst_, .keep = TRUE) %>%
  map_df(~ hr_mcp(., levels = c(0.95)) %>% hr_area) %>%
  mutate(burst_ = unique(mini_deer$burst_), .before = 1)

#  burst_ level what         area
#   <dbl> <dbl> <chr>       <dbl>
#1      1  0.95 estimate  180927.
#2      2  0.95 estimate 1886603.
#3      3  0.95 estimate       0 
#4      4  0.95 estimate       0 
#5      5  0.95 estimate   14476.
```

Answer (score 3):

We could use `nest_by` with `mutate` itself and then `unnest` the `list` column

```
library(amt)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
mini_deer %>% 
    nest_by(burst_) %>%
    transmute(mcparea = list(hr_mcp(data, levels = 0.95) %>% 
                  hr_area))  %>% 
    ungroup %>%
    unnest(mcparea)
# A tibble: 5 x 4
  burst_ level what         area
   <dbl> <dbl> <chr>       <dbl>
1      1  0.95 estimate  180927.
2      2  0.95 estimate 1886603.
3      3  0.95 estimate       0 
4      4  0.95 estimate       0 
5      5  0.95 estimate   14476.
```