# How to Select a Certain number of Rows from a Dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe, slice, extract, rows

I have a little bit of a basic question here, but I'm perplexed by the error I'm receiving. I have a dataframe of 894 rows and would like to extract the first 6.

```
    slice(average_parameters2, 1:6)
  

    head(average_parameters2, 6)


    average_parameters2[1:6, ]
```

I've tried the following methods all of which result in the following error.

```
    Error: The `groups` attribute is not a data frame with its last column called `.rows`.

     > str(average_parameters2)
     grouped_df [894 x 2] (S3: grouped_df/tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
     $ name         : chr [1:894] "Logged.GDP.per.capita" 
     "Social.support" "Healthy.life.expectancy" 
     "Freedom.to.make.life.choices" ...
     $ average_value: num [1:894] 10.2217 0.8926 69.6959 0.8462 -0.0344 
     ...
```

Anyone know what the issue is or something else that may work?

Comment: What does the command `str(average_parameters2)` return? Can you please edit your question to include that information?

Comment: @jared_mamrot it has been edited!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Grouping and nesting data produces an error in R with tidyverse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68098340/grouping-and-nesting-data-produces-an-error-in-r-with-tidyverse)

Comment: Can you add `dput(head(average_parameters2, 10))` to your post so that we have actual data to work with?